# Modelica function, remove input via conversion script

Tags: auto-update, modelica

I have a function with two inputs, the second one has a default value

```
function myfun
  input Real ione;
  input Real itwo=2.0;
  output Real othree;
algorithm
  othree := ione * 3;
end myfun;
```

The function is then used / called in models, sometime the optional input is given, sometimes not.

```
model myModel
  Real a = myfun(1);
  Real b = myfun(1,2);
  Real c = myfun(ione=1.3);
end myModel;
```

But as the second input is not helpful, I would like to remove it, from the function and all places where the function is called, using a conversion script. Is that possible, or do I have to keep the input forever?

Comment: Something like this should do:
convertModifiers("myfun", {"ione"}, fill("",0) ,true);

should work, you will obviously need to give versions to the libraries involved and add the conversion scripts etc.  see https://specification.modelica.org/master/annotations.html#:~:text=internally%20ordered%20alphabetically.-,18.8.2,-Version%20Handling